# Creating unique feature layer from existing layer in ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

In ArcGIS Online, I am creating a new feature layer where I will be hand-tracing features based on an aerial photo. I want to use an existing feature layer with similar data as a base. When I create a copy of the layer in ArcGIS Online (open layer in map > open layer menu > COPY > save copied layer), it creates a dependent copy where any edits to features are transferred back to the original layer.

How do I create a new unique feature layer from the existing data, that I can edit without affecting the original feature layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to approach this problem:

1. Download the current layer as a shapefile, then zip it and upload it again.  This way you will have a duplicate layer that you can edit.
2. Create a new layer in ArcGIS Online and start drawing the new shape from scratch.

[image]